# Include sass in gatsby globally

Tags: sass, gatsby

I have the following project structure:

```
gatsby-config.js
/src
  /components
    layout.jsx
    /button
      button.jsx
      button.scss
  /pages
  /styles
    styles.scss
    _mixins.scss
    _variables.scss
```

and `gatsby-config.js` and `styles.scss` are configured respectively in the following way:

```
...
plugins: [
...,
`gatsby-plugin-sass`
]
...
```

```
@import 'variables',
        'mixins';
```

in order to access the mixins and variables, the `styles.scss` is being currently imported in all the components' scss files, e.g.:

```
//button.scss
@import './../styles/styles.scss'
```

This approach is working, but the problem is, as the project grows, the `styles.scss` is being imported multiple times and seems to be something wrong with this approach.
Is it possible to import `styles.scss` only once, and make all mixins and variables available across all the components?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are able to pass [options](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-sass/#other-options) to Sass via `gatsby-plugin-sass`.

The following options would globally expose the contents of `./src/styles/_styles.scss` to each Sass file in the project, without the need to explicitly import it.

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-sass',
      options: {
        data: `@import "${__dirname}/src/styles/styles";`,
      }
    },
  ],
}
```

---

**Note:** The below might be obvious to some but it's worth mentioning for future readers.

*Only* do this with Sass files that contain just variables, mixins, functions, etc (Sass features that do not output any actual CSS until they are consumed). Otherwise you will end up with CSS that is repeated multiple times across your project.

[Example repo](https://github.com/k-sav/gatsby-scss-demo)

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but with no luck. The terminal was showing `File to import not found or unreadable dir1dir2dir3src/styles/styles`. 
For some strange reason the path shows no slashes between the directories.
I tried then `data: @import "./src/styles/styles"` and the project compiled. However, the styles are added to all files and the problem with the multiple imports still remains.

Comment: Remove anything from the styles folder that would output any css.

Comment: And how should I include the data which produces any css?

Comment: You should probably import the stylesheet to the relevant component.

Comment: If you have some base css inside `styles.css`, import that into your layout component.

Comment: unfortunately I am only using `scss` files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199329/discussion-between-ksav-and-vtolentino).

Comment: Update: This has been changed to `initialData`

Comment: `additionalData`

Comment: Not obvious at all to folks new to Gatsby! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

## Providing SCSS variables globally to your components

- With [`@use`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use)
- SCSS syntax
- gatsby-plugin-sass
- [Component-Scoped Styles with CSS Modules](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/css-modules/)

### gatsby-plugin-sass config

`gatsby-config.js` file:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
  options: {
    implementation: require("sass"),
    data: `@use "${__dirname}/src/global-styles/variables" as var;`
  }
},
```

`var` will be used as [namespace](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#choosing-a-namespace).

### Providing variables to your scss files

```
./src/global-styles/_variables.scss
./src/components/main.jsx
./src/components/main.module.scss
```

Info about the underscore in `_variables.scss`, [partials](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#partials).

`_variables.scss` file:

```
$color-1: red;
$color-2: blue;
```

`main.jsx` file:

```
import React from 'react'
import style from './main.module.scss'

const Main = () => (
    <div className={style.main}>Content</div>
)

export default Main
```

`main.module.scss` file:

```
.main {
    color: var.$color-1;
}
```

### But I need expose some global styles in `gatsby-browser.js`

Well, your are going to need `@use`, or follow other answers that use `@import` in `gatsby-config.js`. Mixing `@import` and `@use` may not work because of:

> Heads up!
>
> A stylesheet’s @use rules must come before any rules other than @forward, including style rules. However, you can declare variables before @use rules to use when configuring modules.
>
> https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use

I stopped using `@import`, only using `@use`.

`global-styles.scss` file:

```
@use "./variables" as var;

body {
    color: var.$color-2;
}
```

`gatsby-browser.js` file:

```
import './src/global-styles/global-styles.scss'
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a file named `gatsby-browser.js` in the root of your directory. Import the `.scss` file once and it will work perfectly .

In your `gatsby-browser.js`

```
import "./src/styles/styles.scss"
```

Comment: I tried importing in the `gatsby-browser.js` but it did not work. In the tutorial they only mention importing css files, not scss

Comment: It works perfectly. What error are you getting? You need to install `node-sass` and `gatsby-plugin-sass` to make that work

Comment: If I only include the `styles.scss` in the `gatsby-config.js` file, the variables and mixins are shown as not defined  e.g. `No mixin named bpTabletPortraitUp`.

Answer (score 2):

As Ankit Sinha mentioned, you can import your styles in `gatsby-browser.js`:

```
import './src/styles/styles.scss';
```

This method is mentioned in [the Gatsby tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-two/).

According to the docs (see [Standard Styling with Global CSS Files](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/global-css/)):

> The best way to add global styles is with a shared layout component.

Your project structure suggests that you are using one (`layout.jsx`). If that's the case, you can also import your styles in `layout.jsx`:

```
import './../styles/styles.scss';
```

Comment: I tried importing in the `gatsby-browser.js` but it did not work. In the tutorial they only mention importing css files, not scss

Answer (score 1):

I cant write comments yet. I dont have the reputation. But what a complete answer from Undefined Behavior.

Just to order a little bit:

- Import your `global-styles.scss` in `gatsby-browser.js`
- Configure something that's going to be exposed to all scss files, in your `gatsby-config.js`.
  It can be an `@import` or an `@use`. With `@import` you access directly to your variables and mixins and with `@use` you reference it. I don't really know what are the benfits of both, but you could use any.