# How to import global SASS with Gatsby

Tags: css, sass, gatsby

I'm trying to have a global .scss file that gets imported into all pages.

I have the following project structure

```
/src
  /pages
    index.js
    index.module.scss
    /templates
      /restaurants
        /hungry
          hungry.js
          hungry.module.scss
  /styles
    typography.scss
    variables.scss
  /package.json
    gatsby-plugin-sass
    node-sass
  /fonts
    ...
```

I tried passing options via `gatsby-plugin-sass` and also exposing global styles with `gatsby-browser.js` using this link: [Include sass in gatsby globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57833884/include-sass-in-gatsby-globally) but no luck.

My typography.scss file

[typography.scss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4w5w.png)

Passing options to gatsby-config.js

[My gatsby-config.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1I2u.png)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTj3a.png)

Exposing global styles with gatsby-browser.js

[gatsby-browser.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNnW9.png)

[hungry.module.scss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9AYe.png)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wU5n.png)

I've also tried reading the documentation:
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/global-css/

I'm new to Gatsby and completely out of ideas at this point. I appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach of using `gatsby-browser.js` is perfectly valid and it should work, in addition, your paths look correct to me.

Regarding your `typography.scss`, it clearly seems that the relative paths are not working, try adding/removing relativity using `../../path/to/fonts` or `./path/to/fonts`.

Another approach that may work for you, is removing the options from your `gatsby-plugin-sass` plugin and import it as `.scss import` to the desired file.

Let's say that you fix the issue with the relative paths in your `typography.scss` (first step). Once done, your `.subtitle` class file, you can simply:

`@import '../../../styles/fonts/typography.scss'` use it. Something like:

```
   @import '../../../styles/fonts/typography.scss
    .subtitle{
       font-family: $font-medium;
    }
```

So, summarizing. The first step should be to fix the relative font importation and then, import that file directly in the needed `.scss` files.

---

Once you comment the manifest plugin (which request a missing asset in the GitHub), it loads the fonts correctly:

[image]

Notice the K, quite unique in this typography.

Gatsby uses the path inside `/pages` folder to build URLs of the pages. You were putting the templates folder inside the `/pages` folder, causing some weird behavior. Move it outside to fix the issue.

Comment: I can't change the path to fonts because they are also used in the index.js file.

Comment: > Regarding your typography.scss, it clearly seems that the relative paths are not working...


I can't change the path to fonts because they are also used in the index.js file.


I tried importing them like you suggested but I get this error:
```Can't resolve '../fonts/HKGrotesk-SemiBold.otf' in '/Users/username/Github/repo/src/pages/templates/restaurants'```


If I place ```hungry.js``` and ```hungry.module.scss``` at ```/pages``` root level it works but not if it's nested page.


Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Can you provide a working sandbox? You don't need to change the path of the fonts, you need to change the relativity of in the `typography.scss` file.

Comment: Here's a minimal example: https://github.com/jovil/sandbox

Thank you.

Comment: The project, once you comment the manifest plugin, works without errors and loads the fonts correctly.

Comment: I'm probably missing something very obvious. I removed the manifest plugin from ```gatsby-config.js``` and ran ```gatsby clean``` and restarted the server.

imported the styles using ```@import '../../../styles/typography.scss';``` but I still get the same error?

Comment: I didn't touch anything, just the repo configuration commenting the manifest.

Comment: Oh I see where the confusion is. The ```index.js``` was already working beforehand. It's the ```hungry.js``` that's the issue.

Comment: I fixed it. Move your templates folder outside the `/pages` (ideally inside components)

Comment: I noticed I just had to move the font-face rules inside the components folder, for some reason, and then it worked. Thanks for the help 